# FluentAssertions - ShouldAllBeEquivalent and Exluding property - failing unexpectedly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I want to assert that the contents of two lists of dtos are equivalent. However, I want one property on each item to be ignored in the comparison. From reading the collections & dictionaries subsection of the [Fluent Assertions documentation](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison), my understanding is that this line should do what I want:

```
response.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.Excluding(activity => activity.ActivityDetails.InternalId));
```

I have written a unit test that should pass, but this statement results in an AssertionException being thrown with the following message:

> Expected item[0].ActivityDetails.InternalId to be 0, but found 19372.
>
> Expected item[1].ActivityDetails.InternalId to be 0, but found 19374.
>
> Expected item[2].ActivityDetails.InternalId to be 0, but found 19376.
>
> With configuration:
>
> Select all declared properties
>
> Exclude property ActivityDetails.InternalId
>
> Match property by name (or throw)
>
> Invoke Action when info.RuntimeType.IsSameOrInherits(System.String)

I have probably misunderstood the documentation. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the types of the ActivityDetails and InternalId properties?

Comment: InternalId is a long. I have reduced ActivityDetails to  `public class ActivityDetails
    {
        public long InternalId { get; set; }
    }`  but the issue persists.

Comment: For what it's worth, other factors have motivated a re-factoring of the project I'm working on. I'm now comparing ActivityDetails objects directly instead of Lists of ActivityDetails. This works with no problems.

Comment: I'm going to investigate this scenario anyhow. What was the type of the `response` variable?

Comment: The response variable was of type ActivitySummary. I can reduce this down to a very simple class containing just the ActivityDetails property and an Id property. I've put up an example of the problem I'm having: https://github.com/cormacwb/FluentAssertionsTest. My (almost certainly incorrect) understanding is that the test in Test.cs should pass, but it fails in the manner described in my question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out somewhere today or tomorrow.